# How to delay after one element animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow

I have a slide show that some Items and images come to my slideshow by jquery animate, This is my code:

```
$("#item-1").animate({left:100},1000,function(){
   $("#item-2").animate({left:250},2000, function(){
      //I want below Item come with a long delay, I mean a delay after #item-2
      $("#item-3").animate({left:100},1250)
   })
});
```

**How to make a delay?**

Comment: you can use jQuery setTimeout Function and try.

Comment: You have to wrap `$("#item-3").animate({left:100},1250)` with `setTimeout()` call

Comment: what is the issue currently you are facing? IMHO it should work fine.

Comment: @Jai Please read my comment inside code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a delay you specify in milliseconds, use `setTimeout`:

```
$("#item-1").animate({left:100},1000,function(){
   $("#item-2").animate({left:250},2000, function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          $("#item-3").animate({left:100},1250)
      }, 2000);
   })
});
```

`setTimeout` basically says: **"perform this function (first parameter), after the specified amount of time (second parameter)"**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: That worked well, I didn't know it before. Thanks Man

Comment: No problem. Quick tip - get that value of `2000` into a variable to make your code more manageable. For example, if you have to change the duration of the animation of item-2, you'll need to change it in two parts of your code. With the use of a variable it's only one part.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a method to deal with this, specifically relating to animation queues:

https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Working example (in my console) below:

```
$("#item-1").animate({left:100},1000,function(){
   $("#item-2").animate({left:250},2000, function(){
      //I want below Item come with a long delay, I mean a delay after #item-2
      $("#item-3").delay(2000).animate({left:100},1250)
   })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Implemented using jQuery setTimeOut function:

```js
$("#item-1").animate({left:100},1000,function(){
   $("#item-2").animate({left:250},2000, function(){
      //I want below Item come with a long delay, I mean a delay after #item-2
      //Trigerring function after specific time .
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       $("#item-3").animate({left:350},1250)
     }, 2000);      
   })
});
```

```css
div{
    color:red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item-1">one</div>
<div id="item-2">two</div>
<div id="item-3">three</div>
```